# Define double letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

in following code how can I say if my argument is correct return True and if it is not correct return False. When I use `return True` it works but when I add (`else`) it does not work anymore.

```
word="FEEEL"

def double(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i]== word[i+1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(double(word))
```

Comment: You return `false` for the first check, if F==E. The function stops on return and thus will never find the double letters.

Answer (score 3):

You don't know to return `False` until you have iterated over all the letters.  So move your `return False` outside of the for-loop:

```
def double(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i]== word[i+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

One improvement to your code would be to use `zip` rather than indexing to pair your letters:

```
def double(word):
    for s, t in zip(word, word[1:]):
        if s == t:
            return True
    return False
```

Your logic is basically "If any letter repeats return true".  So another improvement would be to use `any`:

```
def double(word):
    if any(s==t for s, t in zip(word, word[1:])):
        return True
    return False
```

Which can be shortened to

```
def double(word):
    return any(s==t for s, t in zip(word, word[1:])):
```

Let's give the function a better name:

```
def has_repeated_letter(word):
    return any(s==t for s, t in zip(word, word[1:]))
```

Do you want `'Aardvark'` to evaluate `True` even though it has an upper and lower case "A"?  If so:

```
def has_repeated_letter(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return any(s==t for s, t in zip(word, word[1:]))
```

Another way is to use regular expressions (omit `re.IGNORECASE` if you want `'Aardvark'` to evaluate to `False`):

```
import re
def has_repeated_letter(word):
    return bool(re.search(r'(.)\1', word, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: Or with `itertools.groupby`: `return next((True for _,group in groupby(word) if len(list(group)) > 1),False)`

Comment: @Saram:  Give me an example of the list and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: word_list=["suut","reeta"]

  output: [uu],[ee]

Comment: @Saram:  Now you are wanting to extract data rather than giving True/False.  Talk about moving the goalposts!  `def get_first_repeated_letter(word):m = re.search(r'(.)\1', word, re.I);return m.group(0) if m else ''`.  Then `[get_first_repeated_letter(word) for word in ["suut", "abc", "reeta"]]` gives `['uu', '', 'ee']`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks for the great explanation. Quick question, when using the zip function, you slice the `word` variable from index 1 onwards. Why not from 0?